# how to provide multiple SQS queue name in AWS Lambda trigger cloud formation template

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-cloudformation, amazon-sqs

I want to trigger two different SQS queue from my lambda, in my cloud formation template I gave like this - but my stack is not getting created. I'm getting below error message:

```
Events:
        SQSEvent:
          Type: SQS
          Properties:
            Queues:
              - !Sub arn:aws:sqs:${AWS::Region}:${AccountId}:${QueueName}
              - !Sub arn:aws:sqs:${AWS::Region}:${AccountId}:${DLQQueueName}
            BatchSize: 1
            Enabled: true
```

Transform AWS::Serverless-2016-10-31 failed with: Invalid Serverless Application Specification document.
Number of errors found: 1. Resource with id [MyLambda] is invalid. Event with id [SQSEvent] is invalid. No Queue (for SQS) or Stream (for Kinesis, DynamoDB or MSK) or Broker (for Amazon MQ) provided.04/27/22 06:09:18 - UPDATE_ROLLBACK_IN_PROGRESS - AWS::CloudFormation::Stack) -
Transform AWS::Serverless-2016-10-31 failed with: Invalid Serverless Application Specification document.
Number of errors found: 1. Resource with id [MyLambda] is invalid. Event with id [SQSEvent] is invalid. No Queue (for SQS) or Stream (for Kinesis, DynamoDB or MSK) or Broker (for Amazon MQ) provided.

Can someone please help me to resolve this issue. Appreciated your help!

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You will want to use `Queues` (plural):

```
Events:
        SQSEvent:
          Type: SQS
          Properties:
            Queues:
              - !Sub arn:aws:sqs:${AWS::Region}:${AccountId}:${QueueName}
              - !Sub arn:aws:sqs:${AWS::Region}:${AccountId}:${DLQQueueName}
            BatchSize: 1
            Enabled: true
```

Comment: This is not working, I'm getting an error message: I've updated the original post.

Answer (score 0):

You could check your serverless setup against these templates
https://carova.io/snippets/serverless-aws-create-sqs-queue-template

This one shows the whole setup with your SQS Queue being subscribed to and SNS topic and then triggering the AWS Lambda Function.
https://carova.io/snippets/serverless-aws-sqs-queue-subscribed-to-sns-topic

Answer (score 0):

You can write your template as given below -

```
Events:
  SQSEvent1:
    Type: SQS
    Properties:
      Queue: !Sub arn:aws:sqs:${AWS::Region}:${AccountId}:${QueueName}
      BatchSize: 1
      Enabled: true
  SQSEvent2:
    Type: SQS
    Properties:
      Queue: !Sub arn:aws:sqs:${AWS::Region}:${AccountId}:${DLQQueueName}
      BatchSize: 1
      Enabled: true
```